# How do I create a thumbnail in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, thumbnails, cpanel

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code? It can upload an image but it can't create a 150x150 thumbnail. It works well in my localhost but there seems to be a problem after I transferred it to cpanel.

Here's my code in uploading an image and creating thumbnail:

```
function upload() {

    $config = array(
                    'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
                    'allowed_types' => 'jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp',
                    'max_size' => 2000
                );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
                    'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
                    'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbnails',
                    'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
                    'width' => 150,
                    'height' => 150
                );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $data['image'] = $image_data['file_name'];
    $this->db->where('ID', $this->session->userdata('userID'));
    $query = $this->db->update('member', $data);

    return $query;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors? What image lib are you using (GD/imagemagick)? Can you confirm it's installed and working on your server?

Comment: There are no errors. It just won't create new image for thumbnail. The thumbnail is supposed to be saved in codeigniter/images/thumbnails/.

Comment: I bet there are errors, but probably you don't see them.

Comment: There are no errors messages shown. I tried echoing the source_image and new_image, and the result shows like this:
source_image = /home/bin182/public_html/ci_sample/images/image12.jpg
new_image = /home/bin182/public_html/ci_sample/images/thumbnails